# What's the value of information when we decrease the entropy of a probability distribution?

Tags: estimation, entropy, value-of-information

Suppose you have to choose between actions $A_1,\dots,A_n$. You have a probability distribution over each $U(A_i)$, i.e. over the utility of choosing each action. So you should choose the $A_i$ that maximizes $\mathbf E[U(A_i)]$.

But now you are given the opportunity to reduce your uncertainty about one of these $U(A_i)$. I think the value of this new evidence should be

$$\int_{e\in E}P(e)~\mathbf E[U'(A_i)]~\text{d}e$$

where $E$ contains every possible piece of evidence you could receive, $P(e)$ is how likely it is, and $U'(A_i)$ is the utility of action $A_i$ after you receive the evidence $e$.

And I know I'm pushing it, but: can you think of some way to *roughly estimate* the value of reducing entropy, given only the expectation and current entropy of each $U(A_i)$, and the amount by which you will reduce the entropy of one particular $U(A_i)$? For instance, if $U(A_1)$ has expectation 20 and entropy 10 bits, and you're given the same information about every other $A_i$, how much would you pay to reduce the entropy of $U(A_i)$ by 2 bits?